# How to solve opengl2.1 support problem on PR2?

Tags: ros, moveit-setup-assistant, pr2, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ROS groovy on PR2.

I try to run:

```
ssh -X pr2admin@192.168.2.101
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

But it says:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Your graphics driver does not support OpenGL 2.1. Please enable software rendering before running RViz (e.g. type 'export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1').
```

And I follow its solution two ways but never work.

first:

```
ssh -X pr2admin@192.168.2.101
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

second:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
ssh -X pr2admin@192.168.2.101
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

I found that another laptop can run this launch with PR2 without any problem.

How could I solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196323/how-to-solve-opengl2.1-support-problem-on-pr2?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't run graphical software on the PR2. Instead, set your ROS_MASTER_URI to point to the ros master on the PR2 and run graphical programs locally.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-10-30**:
Thank you~ I try to run `scp pr2admin@192.168.2.101:/etc/ros/groovy/urdf/robot_calibrated_2014_05_08_18_23.xml .`  to copy urdf file to my laptop so that I can run it on my laptop with graphics.